# How to handle concurrent write access to two related tables

Tags: postgresql, concurrency

Suppose there are two tables `t1` and `t2`. `t1` has a `boolean` column `ct1`. 
There are two scenarios:

1. If `ct1` is false, create new entries in `t2` and make `ct1` true
2. If `ct1` is true, just return

How to handle above scenario in Postgres if there are concurrent queries like above?

The possible race condition is: the first query sees `ct1` as false and then create entries in `t2`, then the second query also see `ct1` as false before the first query can make it true.

Comment: It is very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server

Comment: @McNets: The [suggested answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server) is somewhat related, yes. But the referenced answer is about UPSERT in SQL Server, while this one is about `UPDATE` *plus* conditional `INSERT` in Postgres. Different on principal. We do not need the Postgres UPSERT implementation here (`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE`). Concurrency control is simple even with default isolation level `read committed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `UPDATE` takes a write lock on the row automatically, which prevents concurrent transactions from doing the same until the lock is released (your transaction has finished).

So this should do the trick:

```
WITH upd AS (
   UPDATE t1
   SET    ct1 = true
   WHERE  t1.id = $t1_id  -- your input here
   AND    ct1 = false
   RETURNING t1_id
   )
INSERT INTO t2(t1_id, col1)
SELECT t1_id, 'foo'  -- or your input for t2 here
FROM   upd;          -- only if UPDATE found a row
```

This assumes a PK `t1.id` to allow multiple rows in `t1`. Your example makes it seem like there is a single row in `t1`. The same solution would work for that simple case, just remove `t1.id` from the query.

`t1.ct1` must be defined `NOT NULL`.

If the `UPDATE` finds no row (row in t1 with `t1.id = $t1_id` is already `true` or does not exist) then nothing happens.

If concurrent transactions wait to update the same row, they will wake up once this transaction has finished.

If your transaction commits, `ct1` is `true` now, and the recheck for others will return no qualifying row, i.e. concurrent transactions are finished, too.

If your transaction rolls back, the next one in line gets to update `t1` (and hence also insert rows in `t2`).

Note: Normally, queries in CTEs can execute in any order. But since the outer `INSERT` references the `UPDATE`, a sequence of operations is established.

Comment: Thats a great point of view, which has helped to make things clearer for me. Here, is the understanding for me till now: Start transaction with the default isolation level(read committed). The first transaction will update ct1 column and that will force any concurrent transaction to roll back which is how read committed isolation is supposed to work. Found a good slide about isolation levels https://www.postgresql.org/files/developer/concurrency.pdf

Comment: @AmanGupta: Actually, concurrent transactions will ***not*** roll back. They just don't find a row to update (the recheck for  `ct1 = false` excludes the row) and do nothing.

Comment: Ya correct Erwin.

Comment: How about this: Using sequelize(nodejs) which uses repeatable read as the default isolation level. Each transaction will have a snapshot of db at the start of the transaction. Wont update ct1 to true unless insertion in t2 is done(cant make it true at begining). When the transaction comes to update ct1 1. if it is still unchanged, the transaction updates and commits 2. If it is updated by another concurrent transaction, it will rollback(this is how read repeated isolation level behaves) and throw an error, so need to be retried and will get ct1 as true this time

Comment: I have made a change in question on why I cant make ct1 true as the first query, otherwise your solution was perfect.

Comment: Please do not *change* the nature of your question after an answer has been given. Ask a *new question* instead. You can always link to this one for context. I rolled back your last edit.